# How to export/add a single animation into Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity

I have a spaceship, with a lot of animations (using a rig/armature) already working inside Unity. Now I wanted to add a new animation, I do so in Blender, but can't figure out how to add just that one new animation (action) from Blender to Unity.

I've tried exporting the FBX with the new animation, and replace it with the FBX inside Unity, but doing so the new animation does not appear (it does if I do add it as a new FBX with a different name instead of replacing it).
How can I do so?

Comment: Hello and welcome! BSE is a question and answer site. It works more like a library than a common forum. If you have found a solution to your problem feel free to post it as an answer. After 2 days, you even can accept your own answer. The accepted answer has a checkmark and is linked to the question in the search result. This way other readers can easily find it. If you do so there is no need to add "(Solved)" to the title.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the file is the way. Animations will not show up straight ahead. Once replaced the file, open the fbx (top right corner in inspector, click "open"), go to the Animations tab, then the + icon, and then select the new animation, and on the dropdown below Source Take select the newly added animation.